# How can I generate parentkey dynamically for a Vega stratify graph

Tags: kibana, vega

I am using vega (vega 3.0) to plot a tree graph in Kibana. I am using stratify to transform my data. I have the key field for stratify transformation, but dont have the parentKey field in my data. I want to generate the parentKey from my existing Data based on the following logic.

1. For each node in the data, it's parent will have step_id=(current step_id)-1.
2. There is possibility to have multiple nodes which mach step_id=(current step_id)-1. I want to filter the only node which has timestamp most immediate previous to the current node's timestamp.

I have two questions here.

- Can I perform a search in my elasticsearch database with the above two conditions, directly from a Vega transformation? I dont see any API call or search posiibility from the documentation. Please let me know if it is possible.
- If a direct search is not possible. Then how can I do it using the existing transformation rule?

I have tried with lookup transformation and I can successfully apply #1 rule as mentioned above. But I can not inject #2 rule along with it. I can not see lookup with two different keys and that too for a range of value.

I am trying to look into lookup implementation in the Vega source. But before that want to understand if this is possible with the existing transformation. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Vega transforms "cross", "window" ("rank" operator) and "filter" are used to find the most recent parent for each item: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/cross/ https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/window/ https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/filter/

Thanks to Roy I for answering this - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vega-js/Q2XrYMOVluw